# Facebook App Error : Invalid parameter (FacebookException)

Tags: facebook, forms-authentication

I have a strange problem with my basic Facebook app.

I followed the below URL to develop basics of my app.

http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/facebook-application-development-using-asp-net-and-facebooktoolkit-version-3-0/

The first time it is showing the data (user name and uid). But when I refresh the page, it is giving me some exception and goes to error page.

```
Exception type: FacebookException 

Exception message: Invalid parameter
```

Do you have any clue about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

How are you refreshing the page? Use Firebug or httpfox or something to see exaclty what parameters you are sending. If you are refreshing the browser window, you might not have the same params that you started with when you accessed the page directly.

Comment: The problem is not browser specific. I have tried it across browsers. I am using F5 and refresh button to refresh the page.
Page refresh is not the issue. On any postback action it is also landing into error page with exactly same error msg.

Comment: Browser won't make any difference - if you refresh the page, it will refresh with the parameters that you have there already. If you aren't getting the error when you visit the page directly, it will be to do with the refresh. What parameters are being sent when you refresh the page? Check using a browser tool and once you know which parameter is causing the problem, it should be easy fix from there.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook sends POST variables to your iframe when it is loaded.  Sometimes a browser doesn't properly send those variables when you do a simple refresh, often it is best to navigate to the same url, doing something like:

```
top.location.href = ___current_url___;
```

Comment: The problem is not browser specific. I have tried it across browsers. I am using F5 and refresh button to refresh the page.

Comment: Page refresh is not the issue. On any postback action it is also landing into error page with exactly same error msg.

Comment: I'd suggest doing a var_dump().  From my experience, doing a refresh didn't always send the necessary POST vars.